# Rotate IP outbound IP address in Ubuntu or CentOS

Tags: ubuntu, centos, networking, network-interface

My OpenVZ VPS has two IPv4 and two IPv6 addresses:

```
23.54.xx.102
23.54.xx.103
2604:xxxx:1::xxxx:6x0b
2604:xxxx:1::xxxx:5x7c
```

Now I want to rotate my outbound IP so that when I run any PHP, ruby or curl commands, they rotate through my IP's. I am doing a test with curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json', which shows me the same IP each time.

```
root@local:~#curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json' {"ip":"23.54.xx.102"}
root@local:~#curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json' {"ip":"23.54.xx.102"}
root@local:~#curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json' {"ip":"23.54.xx.102"}
```

I used some StackExchange tables rules but the result is the same -- not rotating IP.

I want the result:

```
root@local:~#curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json' {"ip":"23.54.xx.102"}
root@local:~#curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json' {"ip":"23.54.xx.103"}
root@local:~#curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json' {"ip":"2604:xxxx:1::xxxx:6x0b"}
root@local:~#curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json' {"ip":"2604:xxxx:1::xxxx:5x7c"}
```

is it possible to rotate ip through IPtables and i want to use php,ruby and python.

Comment: I updated the wording of the Q a bit; please make sure it still means what you intended, otherwise, feel free to roll back the change.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
curl --interface 23.54.xx.102 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json' {"ip":"23.54.xx.102"}
```

From curl man page:

> ```
>    --interface <name>
>           Perform an operation using a specified interface. You can enter interface name, IP address or host name. An example could look like:
>            curl --interface eth0:1 http://www.netscape.com/
>
>           If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.
> ```

Comment: yes I know above solution and above solution work with only curl I want to rotate my ip so all outgoing traffic rotates ip. i want to use php & ruby......